# Why is my jquery slideToggle dropdown jerky / wobbly?

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, jquery-hover

I'm writing a web page with a dropdown login script.
I'm using jquery slideToggle() on a list item to show a login form on hover.

Can anyone tell me why my dropdown form feels jerky / wobbly at times when I mouseof?

P.S. Login "button" will not be shown between 625px and 750px

```js
$("#login").hover(function() {
 $("#login-form").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
body {
 background: gray url("../img/bg-default.png") no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 font-size: 85%;
 font-family: Arial, 'Lucicda Sans Unicode';
 line-height: 1.5;
 text-align: left;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 70%;
 clear: both;
}

a {
 color: #474E69; /*#CF5C3F;*/
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:link, a:visited {
 color: #474E69; /*#CF5C3F;*/
}

a:hover, a:active {
 color: white;
 background-color: #474E69; /*#CF5C3F;*/
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}


/* HTML4 FALLBACK */
header, section, footer, aside, nav, main, article, figure {
    display: block; 
}


/* HEADER */
.main-header img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}


/* NAVIGATION */
.navigation {
 background-color: #666;
 height: 40px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
 padding-right: 40px;
}

.navigation ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.navigation ul.main-nav li {
 float: left;
 display: inline;
}

.navigation ul.ext-nav li {
 float: right;
 display: inline;
}

.navigation ul li a {
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.navigation a:link, .navigation a:visited {
 color: white;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 height: 20px
}

.navigation a:hover, .navigation a:active, .navigation .active a:link, .navigation .active a:visited {
 background-color: #474E69; /*#CF5C3F;*/
 text-shadow: none;
}


/* CONTENT */
.main-content {
 width: 70%;
 float: left;
 line-height: 25px;
}

.main-content article {
 background-color: white;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 2% 5%;
 margin-bottom: 3%;
}

.main-content .post-info {
 font-style: italic;
 font-size: 80%;
 color: #999;
}



/* SIDEBAR */
.sidebar {
 width: 28%;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 2%;
}

.sidebar article {
 background-color: white;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 2% 5%;
 margin-bottom: 8%;
}


/* FOOTER */
.main-footer {
 width: 100%;
 height: 40px;
 float: left;
 clear: both;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 background-color: #666;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.main-footer p {
 margin: 10px auto;
}

/* login.css */
#login-form  {
 position: absolute;
 right: 15%;
    display: none;
    float: right;
    clear: both;
    background-color: #666;
    padding: 0 2% 2% 2%;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

#login-form .text {
 width: 100%;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}

#login-form .submit {
    float: right;
}

/* mobile.css */
/* SCREENS LOWER THAN 750xp NO LOGIN */
@media only screen and (min-width: 625px) and (max-width: 750px) { 
 .navigation ul.ext-nav {
  display: none;
 }
 
 .navigation {
        padding-right: 0;
 }
}


/* SCREENS BETWEEN 150px & 600px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 625px) {
 body {
  width: 90%;
  font-size: 95%;
 }
 
 .navigation {
  height: 200px;
        padding-right: 0;
 }
 
 .navigation ul {
  padding-left: 0;
 }
 
 .navigation ul li {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
 }
 
 .navigation a:link, .navigation a:visited {
  padding: 10px 25px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
 }
    
    #login-form  {
        width: 86%;
        right: 5%;
    }
  
 .main-content {
  width: 100%;
 }
 
 .main-content article {
  margin-bottom: 2%;
 }
 
 .post-info {
  display: none;
 }
 
 .sidebar {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
 }
 
 .sidebar article {
  padding: 2% 3%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>iRock.no</title>
  
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mobile.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css" />
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script/login.js"></script>
  <!-- IE9 AND LESS HTML5 SUPPORT -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
 </head>

 <body>
 
  <!-- HEADER -->
  <header class="main-header">
   <img alt="Header" src="http://lorempixel.com/1280/300/iRock-3ngineering/">
  </header>
  
  
  <!-- NAVIGATION -->
  <nav class="navigation">
   <ul class="main-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Workspace</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
   
   <ul class="ext-nav">
    <li id="login">
     <a  href="#" margin-right="40px">login</a>
     <form id="login-form" action="script/login.php" method="post">
               <p><input class="text" type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /></p>
               <p><input class="text" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" /></p>
               <p><input class="submit" type="submit" value="submit" /></p>
     </form>
    </li>
    
   </ul>
  </nav>
  
  
  <!-- CONTENT -->
  <section class="main-content">
   <!-- TODO: program article generator -->
   <article>
    <header class="article-header">
     <h1><a href="#">First Article</a></h1>
    </header>
    
    <footer>
     <p class="post-info">by iRock</p>
    </footer>
    
    <content>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, erant tempor fuisset ea nec. 
     Ius harum lobortis ex, paulo iuvaret argumentum his ex. 
     Vel ne vocibus menandri constituto. 
     Populo salutatus patrioque est in. 
     Id laoreet propriae consulatu mel. 
     Assum prodesset at eos, ius at tota dolorum adversarium. 
     Ad inani impetus impedit duo, an quo tempor laoreet.</p>

     <p>Tantas similique eum id, idque veniam duo ei, ei commodo honestatis pri. 
     Ei sit ignota possit, ex vidisse iracundia his. 
     Eu propriae salutandi est. 
     Pro possim tibique at, at usu simul lobortis. 
     Latine incorrupte disputationi ad vel, integre detracto ei qui. 
     Sit ut illud scripta scribentur, has fastidii invenire voluptatibus in.</p>
    </content>
   </article>
   
   <article>
    <header class="article-header">
     <h1><a href="#">Second Article</a></h1>
    </header>
    
    <footer>
     <p class="post-info">by iRock</p>
    </footer>
    
    <content>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, erant tempor fuisset ea nec. 
     Ius harum lobortis ex, paulo iuvaret argumentum his ex. 
     Vel ne vocibus menandri constituto. 
     Populo salutatus patrioque est in. 
     Id laoreet propriae consulatu mel. 
     Assum prodesset at eos, ius at tota dolorum adversarium. 
     Ad inani impetus impedit duo, an quo tempor laoreet.</p>

     <p>Tantas similique eum id, idque veniam duo ei, ei commodo honestatis pri. 
     Ei sit ignota possit, ex vidisse iracundia his. 
     Eu propriae salutandi est. 
     Pro possim tibique at, at usu simul lobortis. 
     Latine incorrupte disputationi ad vel, integre detracto ei qui. 
     Sit ut illud scripta scribentur, has fastidii invenire voluptatibus in.</p>
    </content>
   </article>
   
  </section>
  
  
  <!-- SIDEBAR -->
  <aside class="sidebar">
   <article>
    <h1><a href="#">Sidebar Article 1</a></h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, erant tempor fuisset ea nec. 
     Ius harum lobortis ex, paulo iuvaret argumentum his ex.</p>
   </article>
   
   <article>
    <h1><a href="#">Sidebar Article 2</a></h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, erant tempor fuisset ea nec. 
     Ius harum lobortis ex, paulo iuvaret argumentum his ex.</p>
   </article>
   
   <article>
    <h1><a href="#">Sidebar Article 3</a></h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, erant tempor fuisset ea nec. 
     Ius harum lobortis ex, paulo iuvaret argumentum his ex.</p>
   </article>
  </aside>
  
  
  <!-- FOOTER -->
  <footer class="main-footer">
   <p>Copyright &copy; Øystein Jacobsen</p>
  </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I don't see anything wrong. Mouseover and mouseout work's the same.
I am using latest chrome. Nothing wrong in the script aswell.
Anyway, I don't recommend such solution as a login, It will frustrate your guests ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `height` is not a very performant CSS attribute to animate (which is what `slideToggle()` is doing under the covers), even if you were using CSS animations instead of jQuery. This is because the browser has to recalculate layout, re-paint the affected areas (or perhaps even the whole page), and then re-composite the layers. In essence, it has to do a lot of work and can have a hard time doing it 60 times per second so that we perceive it as a smooth animation—let's say it can only can do all that 15 times per second, and we perceive "jank" or "lag." This will of course be different on every computer that views your website; more powerful machines will see the smooth animation but less capable machines (like mobile phones, for example) will have a harder time.

If you wanted a more performant animation, you could animate the `opacity`, (preferably with CSS instead of jQuery). When the browser animates `opacity`, it only has to re-composite, *not* re-calculate layout and re-paint. It is much easier to do that at 60 frames per second. So you would fade in and out your form instead of having it slide up and down.